# Scala test verify expectation internal attributes in a class

Tags: scala, unit-testing, amazon-s3, scalatest, region

I am writing unit test to verify the expectation that whether custom region is passed correctly.

```
def methodToTest(bucket: String, key: Path, customRegion) {
    S3.download(bucket, key, None, None, None)
      .withAttributes(S3Attributes.settings.getCustomSettings(s3Settings, customRegion))
      .....
}
```

The #getCustomSettings is a private method which takes `region` as parameter and returns `S3Settings` as follows:

```
private def getCustomSettings(s3Settings: S3Settings, customRegion: String): S3Settings = {
    settings.withS3RegionProvider(new AWSRegionProvider { 
             override def getRegion: Region = Region.of(customRegion)        
    })
}
```

I tried separately testing the private method but I want to test the verification of expectation to check what custom region is passed to it using `scalatest`? Thanks

EDIT: S3Settings is a final class which cannot be mocked like mock[S3Settings]

Answer (score 0):

If `getCustomSettings` is private, you cannot be calling it like that from outside of the `S3Attributes.settings` instance, so I am going to assume you are mistaken about that.

Now, to answer your question, you need to mock the `settings` instance, used by the method getting tested. Something like this for example (assuming the type of `S3Attributes.settings` is `S`:

```
    def methodToTest(
       bucket: String, 
       key: Path, 
       customRegion: String, 
       settings: S = S3Attributes.settings
    ) = {
       S3.download(bucket, key, None, None, None)
      .withAttributes(settings.getCustomSettings(s3Settings, customRegion))
      .....
    }
```

Then in your test:

```
   val settings = mock[S]
   when(settings.getCustomSettings(any, any)).thenAnswer { 
    (s: S3Settings, _: String) => s
   }
   methodToTest("foo", "bar", "baz", settings) 
   verify(settings).getCustomSettings(any, eq("baz"))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I don't want to change access for #getCustomSettings if there is a limitation in scalatest. 1. I just want to assert that the customRegion I am passing through is the same. I am assuming it to be a common situation to test. 2. I should have mentioned this but `S3Settings` is a final class which cannot be mocked

Comment: Well, "don't want" is a serious objection :) But private methods cannot be accessed from outside of their instance, so that's out of the question. As to the class being final, make a trait exposing the interface you need, and then mock that.